# Remove-AppxPackage did not remove the files from WindowsApps

Tags: windows-10

I have tried to remove Hidden City and Candy Crush Saga from a machine.

It does not list anymore when I do a `Get-AppxPackage –AllUsers | Select Name, PackageFullName` but the files still remain. I am unable to delete the files from that folder as well. Is there anybody that can assist me removing these files from the computer. It use over 20GB of space, and it is a Kiosk Machine.

I also tried `psexec -s powershell -c "get-appxpackage -allusers *828B5831.HiddenCityMysteryofShadows* | remove-appxpackage"` with no success

Comment: When you ran that command what visual response did you see, in other words, were the applications uninstalled? How exactly are you determining the applications are still installed? The existence of a folder in WindowsApps isn’t necessarily a valid determining factor